# objective-c iPad Chart/graph

Tags: objective-c, ipad, graph, charts

does anybuddy know, any good third party charts/graphs provider for iPad which we can use in business applications?

Apart from core-plot.

Answer (score 1):

Core Plot is a plotting framework for Mac OS X and iOS. It provides 2D visualization of data, and is tightly integrated with Apple technologies like Core Animation, Core Data, and Cocoa Bindings.

[Core-plot](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/) and also have look to [PowerPlot](http://powerplot.nua-schroers.de/)

Comment: do you know any other provider like telerik ?

Answer (score 1):

From a review I did recently there are very few good iOS charting components. Most are pitifully slow, which spoils the tablet / phone user experience. I was made aware recently of a newcomer to iOS charting by [ShinobiControls](http://www.shinobicontrols.com/). They have some pretty good looking charts:

[image]

But what really sets them aside is the speed, I downloaded the trial and was amazed to see charts with 100,000+ points rendering at 60fps and multi-touch support.

I have used CorePlot and this seriously beats it by a long way!